# customize node shape with brackets

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I convert below code to a customize shape?

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{
        every text node part/.style={align=center},
        brackets/.style={decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt}},
    }
    \node[] (A) {A\\B\\C};
    \draw[brackets] (A.north east) -- (A.south east);
    \draw[brackets] (A.south west) -- (A.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I know pdfdeclareshape but don't know how to draw a brackets in it.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have the following solution that shifts the point where things happen.  I think that the construction must be made in the content of the node, but not in the node style itself.
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


\newcommand{\bnode}[1]{$\displaystyle\left\{\begin{matrix}#1\end{matrix}\right\}$}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path (0, 0) node[draw, circle, outer sep=1ex] (A) {};
  \path (3, 0) node (B) {\bnode{A\\B\\C}};
  \path (A) edge (B);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```